# Make HTTP Call From SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm wondering if there's a way to make an http call from an SSRS report automatically. I'm aware that I can add a Go To URL option in a textbox action. This is not optimal, since it requires the user to click the box. I've tried the following code in ReportProperties>Code and got a syntax error on line 1. Using SSRS 2012.

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://myserver:myport/Request", False
```

I do have some experience with SSRS but am pretty lost here. Also- please don't ask why I need to do this, as it's a pretty long story. It's for some printing solutions that we use, and I assure you, I do need to do it this way (if possible). Thanks!

Comment: I think you **need** a type for your DIM. Have you tried `Dim objRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP`?

Comment: Thanks. So it's super hacky but if you add an image, then put the URL as the image path, it calls the URL when the report is run. It only has to work for like two weeks until we can get a full release out so I'm just going to go with that.